# Mobile version of Orbeon forms

Tags: mobile, orbeon, xforms

We are considering the development of a mobile application to manage offline xforms just like the ODK Collect application for Android. I would like to ask if there is any progress regarding the plan of Orbeon to provide the Orbeon forms Engine for mobile applications. If not, could we use any available Orbeon forms code base in order to start building this kind of application?

Thank you

Comment: By "could we use any available Orbeon forms code base in order to start building this kind of application?" what do you mean exactly? There is Orbeon Forms CE, which is fully open source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, Orbeon Forms works on mobile devices with a regular web browser, just not offline or embedded within a native app. Issue [#1221](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1221) covers that, as well as [#1545](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1545). But there has been no significant progress specifically in that direction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What we actually need is an Embedded XForms Server for mobile clients as mentioned in issue #1221. Since this kind of server is not available, my next question was if we could somehow start building this kind of application under your guidance as an open source project.